# Training a model using a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow

I am trying to understand this(https://www.kaggle.com/reighns/groupkfold-and-stratified-groupkfold-efficientnet) implementation of a ML model by implementing my own adjusted version of it.

Using the same data set as in the example, the tf.dataset object is produced using:

```
train_dataset_fold_1 = (
    tf.data.Dataset
    .from_tensor_slices((train_paths_fold_1, train_labels_fold_1))
    .map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .map(data_augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .repeat()
    .shuffle(512)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(AUTO))
```

The model I am trying to learn with is:

```
def get_model():
    with strategy.scope():
        return Sequential(
            [Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu', input_shape = (256, 256,3)),
            BatchNormalization(),
            Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
            Dropout(0.25),
            Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'),
            BatchNormalization(),
            Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
            Dropout(0.25),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(256, activation = "relu"),
            Dropout(0.5),
            Dense(2, activation = "softmax")])
```

I am getting the following error when I attempt to train however:

```
AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

And I am training as:

```
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', 
                                            patience=3, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.00001)
model_fold_1 = get_model()
history_1 = model_fold_1.fit(train_dataset_fold_1,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    verbose = 1,
                    callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction],
                    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                    validation_data=valid_dataset_fold_1)
```

This seems to be something to do with the training data input format.

Currently this is a tensorflow Tensor, which is produced using the functions decode_image and data_augmentation. I think the error is arising since some np array method is being called on the input. However, when I try to change the code in the decode and augment functions, then the Tensor speed-up is lost.

Is there any quick way to fix this?

Comment: You seem to be using your dataset as if it were a NumPy array at some point, but you are not showing how you are using `train_dataset_fold_1`.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to add that and I have now